# Express send data to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am trying to find a solution to send data via a render page in the `express route` to a `React` component. Basically, I have a `<a />` tag to which I've attached a hyperlink containing parameters, which are being send to the `express` app. Based on these parameters, I want to interrogate a database, and send this data along with the `render` page, trying to achieve a dynamic behavior of the page.
My `<a/>` tag is included on another page, and has the following form:

```
<a href={"/view-ticket/" + data.id}>
```

where `data.id` is the `id` of an item in my database(for example 2)

This is my `express` route:

```
router.get('/view-ticket/:id', (request, response) => {
    database.query('SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id = ?', request.params.id, (error, result, fields) => {
        if(error){
            console.log('Error: ' + error.code);
        }
        console.log(result[0]);
        response.render(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views', 'ticket.pug'));
        // send data from database with the render page
        // response.send() send a JSON that is displayed on the page
    })

});
```

And this is my React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class ViewTicket extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // catch the response somehow via axios, if possible
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div class="view-ticket col"></div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<ViewTicket/>, document.getElementById('ticket'));

export default ViewTicket;
```

Is it possible using basic `GET`, `POST` methods, or do I need to do something more drastic, like using `cookies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest models for interacting between backend and frontend is REST request/responses. You have axios there which you can make the request with to a specific endpoint: /view-ticket/:id and then in the axios callback youll have access to a response object which will have the returned data. You'd use GET for this most likely, apply the data to your react component state, and call setState when you want to change update the data with the response data. That will cause the page to re-render.

Comment: Thing is I do not want to make a request from the React component, I want to send the information when the render page is sent to the browser, and somehow catch this data from the component with axios, preferably.

Comment: Okay, in this case REST request wont be what you need. Could you clarify what you mean by "render page is sent to the browser"?

Comment: So `express` uses `response.send()` to `send` the page to the browser, so it can render it(a stream of bytes). Beside this stream that is the page itself, I want to include the data from the database, but to be also be able to catch it from the `React` component. Request/ response won't work since the component does not know about the `id` that I use to interrogate the database.

Comment: Basically, what I am doing is: I click on a hyperlink on a different page, this hyperlink looks like this: `/view-ticket/2`(2 is the `id` of an ticket in the database). This link corresponds to a `route` in my `express app`. I extract the `id` and the interrogate the database. If successful, I render the page where I should display this data from the database, but I need to send it somehow. In the page there is a React component that should get this data, and create it's `state` based on this database data.

Answer (score 0):

From React point of view you should setup a state first that will hold data from backend. Then you can use axios to fetch data in React life-cycle event when component is loading. After successfull http call you will set state of component to data received from backend. That will automatically cause component to re-render iteself. In render method you will check if your state holds a data for a ticket and only then it will render your component.

IMPORTANT : This is valid if your response holds an object not an array and in render method you can display properies of your ticket.

If you have multiple tickets then make a ViewTickets your root component that will render each ticket with link to ticket details.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ViewTicket } from '<path_to_file>';

class ViewTickets extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { tickets : null };
    }
    componenentWillMount() {
       axios.get(<your_url_that_gets_all_tickets>).then(response => this.setState({tickets : response}));
    }
    render(){
        const { tickets } = this.state;
        return (
            {!!tickets &&
               tickets.map(ticket => (<ViewTicket id={ticket.id} url={ ticket.url } />))
            }
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<ViewTickets/>, document.getElementById('ticket'));

export default ViewTickets;

// View ticket component

export const ViewTicket = (props) => (<div class="view-ticket col"><a href={this.props.url}>Link</a></div>);
```

Comment: I want to use this React page as a template that I only fill up with data from database. I do not know the full `url` so I can initiate call to backend(my url contains an `id` that is not available to the component, but is available to backend), so the logical way is to send the data from the backend first(somehow), and somehow use it in the component. But I have not found a way to send it when also I am calling `route.render`.

Comment: How does one create an user page in React that you can trigger from a button from a menu from another page?

Comment: Well then you can make a higher (parent) component that will first get all the links from backend, I'm not sure what you are trying to do exatcly.

Comment: If you trigger from a menu and then navigate to a page you can pick up link from url and then render it if that is what you are after.

Comment: I want to create a system similar to that of JIRA, and and create a page that will display information of a ticket. Having a lot of tickets, I want to make only one React component that will use data that I feed it from the database.

Comment: Create then ViewTickets component that will get all the tickets from backend and then render each as ViewTicket component. When user click on ViewTicket component then you should reach for your specific controller with that id. Then you can set the ViewTicketDetails component that will show ticket details. This is logical way and basically how Jira does it.